# org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException:No body available of type:

Tags: apache-camel

I have Process model class converting as:

```
<convertBodyTo type="com.sample.Process" />

My assumption getting body null.

org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException:No body available of type: com.sample.Process but has type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList on: Message[000000]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList to the required type: com.sample.Process. Exchange[]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList to the required type: com.sample.Process]
```

Comment: What does your converter method look like? Did you make the converter available/discoverable as documented at https://camel.apache.org/manual/type-converter.html

Comment: I am only converting payload(request ) to Process Pojo class and using  <convertBodyTo type="com.sample.Process" /> 
. I am new in camel so miss your point like  converter method , please let me know any input on this.

Comment: Please read the link I shared. You need to supply a method that does the conversion.